# opencv face detection

Tags: c, eclipse, ubuntu, opencv

I installed opencv2.3 on Ubuntu 11.10 by adding the PPA and it works fine. I've done simple image and video processing programs in it using Eclipse. Now for face detection I was following

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection

And what I do not understand is where to find the /samples/c library that they've mentioned in the "On Linux" section. Apparently I need to change the mode of a file in that directory.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

They actually refer to `opencv-0.9.7/samples/c/` which indicates a jurassic OpenCV version.

However, if you download the sources of the newest version (2.3.1 I guess) you will find that there's an example located at: `samples/c/facedetect.cpp`

Now it's up to you to find if **facedetect.cpp** and the other samples were installed by the pkg manager on your system.

Comment: but where would i find the samples folder?

Comment: If you are asking me that then most probably the samples are not included in the pkg you installed. Download the sources!